# Proof of Proposition 8.2 Neukirch

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am stuck at proving Proposition 8.2 in Neukirch's algebraic number theory (see [http://www.math.toronto.edu/~ila/Neukirch_Algebraic_number_theory.pdf](http://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Eila/Neukirch_Algebraic_number_theory.pdf)). This proposition states the fundamental identity
$$\Sigma e_if_i = n$$ for a separable field extension $L/K$ of degree $n$ and the corresponding ramification indices $e_i$ and inertia degrees $f_i$.

The proof bases on the chinese remainder theorem. I don't understand two points he makes:

Why does the matrix $(a_{ij})$ have entries in $p$ (in my opinion, it is clear that they are in $o$, but I don't see why they should necessarily be in $p$)

Furthermore in the proof of the "second identity", how does he get from a descending chain $O/P_i^{e_i} \supseteq P_i/P_i^{e_i} \supseteq \ldots \supseteq P_i^{e_{i-1}}/P_i^{e_i}$ with successive quotients of form $P_i^n/P_i^{n+1}$ that the dimesion of $O/P_i^{e_i}$ is the sum of the dimensions of the successive quotients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, it follows directly from $\mathfrak{p}N=N$. Finding $\beta$ such that $q\beta=\alpha_i$ for some $q\in\frak{p}$, you could write
$$\beta = \sum_j a_{ij}\alpha_j, \quad a_{ij}\in \mathcal{o},$$
and thus

$$\alpha_i = q\beta = \sum_j (qa_{ij})\alpha_j,$$
and now $qa_{ij}\in \frak{p}$.

For the second question, you can think of it as simply extending a basis at each step, the quotient being exactly the span of the newly added basis elements. Thus counting the dimensions for each quotient is counting the number of added basis elements. A more rigourous argument could be made with the rank-nullity theorem, but hopefully this suffices.

Comment: The first is not quite true: in general there is no $q \in \mathfrak{p}, \beta \in N$ with $\alpha_i = q\beta$. It is $\mathfrak{p}N = \{\sum_i \lambda_ix_i | x_i \in N, \lambda_i \in \mathfrak{p}\}$.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Of course, the proof is easily amended: Take $\sum_j\lambda_j\beta_j = \alpha_i$ with $\lambda_j\in\mathfrak{p}$, expand each $\beta_j$ in the $\alpha_i$-basis and collect terms. The coefficients are then sums of elements of $\frak{p}$, thus still contained in $\frak{p}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is $\mathfrak{p}N = N$, so $\alpha_i = \sum_j a_{ij}\alpha_j$ for some $a_{ij} \in \mathfrak{p}$.

For the second: Suppose $V_0 \supseteq V_{1} \supseteq ... \supseteq V_n \supseteq 0=V_{n+1}$ is a chain of vector spaces. Take a basis of $V_n$ then complete it to a basis of $V_{n-1}$, then to a basis of $V_{n-2}$ and so on. Then $\dim V_0 = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \dim (V_i/V_{i+1})$ by counting the bases (telescopic sum).